# Make ngTags scrollable

Tags: ng-tags-input

Can anyone tell me how to make ng-input-tag(Angular) scrollable in X-direction.
Currently if I insert the tags then the height of the div increases.
What I want is that If I go on inserting the tags then it should scroll in X-direction

I have tried:
width: auto;height: 34px;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;white-space: nowrap;
But it didn't work as expected

So let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: hey even I tried to do so..but couldnt.. hey all guys.. please tell the answer if you know this..... and can any one please tell me what the tabindex property does in ng-tags input control

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but I have seen similar questions go unanswered recently and this one is at the top of a google search for this problem. This can be done using only CSS. If you would like an added visual effect, try customizing the scrollbar.

**For the X direction:**

This can get a bit ugly if you decide to set a min-width or width on your tags.

The only way I've found to do it in the X direction is using flexbox:

```
tags-input .tags .tag-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

tags-input .tags .tag-item {
    /* Applying this display class */
    display: inline-table;        

    /* OR set the tag width to ensure that the text is visible */
    min-width: 150px; /* Could also use width: 123px */
}
```

[This Github issue is also directly related to the problem.](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/472)

**For the Y direction:**

Applying a fixed height to the `.tags` class and setting the `overflow-y` to scroll will give you the desired result:

```
.tags {
    height: 34px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

simple css to add on tags-input class for scroll on x and y axis

```css
.tags-input {
      max-width: 100%;
      line-height: 22px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      height: 65px;
      cursor: text;
 }
```

Comment: Please add explanation of your solution.see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You want me to add comment for each Line of CSS??

Comment: just brief of why you solution works, maybe a link to tutorial/docs, for example as per overflow-x docs scroll value ensure scrollable ...